# jquery inquiry regarding the post method

Tags: jquery

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

i am currently reading the tutorial and paused at the  "Pass Parameters Through the GET Method" part.

```
$("#load_get").click(function(){  
    $("#result")  
        .html(ajax_load)  
        .load(loadUrl, "language=php&version=5");  
});
```

looking at the second parameter of the `.load` function, is it necessary to pass those values  when load the php file? Could i leave it blank?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could leave it blank. The only required argument is the first one (the URL). See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Here's the relevant part. Arguments in square brackets are optional:

> .load( url, [data], [complete(responseText, textStatus,
>   XMLHttpRequest)] )

For example, the following will simply load whatever is at `loadUrl` into the element selected by `#someElement`:

```
$("#someElement").load(loadUrl);
```

Also note that despite how it may appear, the `complete` callback does not have to be the third argument. You can simply miss out the `data` argument if you don't need it:

```
$("#someElement").load(loadUrl, function() {
    //Done!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your PHP file needs to display its content, if you aren't using those Querystrings values then don't include those.